# How do I add an element to a section from the site?

Tags: craft3

I use Craft CMS 4.2.3. I can't find information on how to add an element from the site to a certain section. Please help me solve the problem. It would be very cool if it were some simple example. Thank you in advance.

I mean to add an element to the section not through the administrative panel. And, for example, create a form on the site and through it add an element to the section.

Answer (score 4):

There's two methods for this, the first one I'll assume your frontend form doesnt directly make a new entry, but does other things and triggers a new entry *as well*. The second, I will assume your form is directly making an entry as soon as you hit submit, and is getting all of your entry info from the form itself.

**METHOD 1 - THE FORM IS NOT THE ENTRY INFO**

To do this via PHP you will need to create a Module. Modules are a Yii convention for extending PHP functionality.

Start Here in the "Extending Craft" docs: https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/module-guide.html

Then, you will want to create a public controller for the module, which you can call as the form's action in your code.

Controllers Guide:
https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/extend/controllers.html#creating-a-controller

Since you are looking to make new entries, the entries guide is your next stop: https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/entries.html

**METHOD 2 - THE FORM IS THE ENTRY INFO**

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="send-form" id="send-form">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="entries/saveEntry"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="sectionId" value="X"> // Required! ID# of the section
    <input type="hidden" name="typeId" value="X"> // ID# of the entry type
    <input type="hidden" name="enabled" value="1">
    
    <label>Text Field
        <input type="text" name="fields[customField]" value="">
    </label>

    [... some more fields ...]

     <input class="btn-vote" type="submit" value="send">

</form>
```

Here's some guides and help for frontend forms:

Matrix (New & Editing Existing): [adding a block of matrix field from a front end entry form](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/36017/adding-a-block-of-matrix-field-from-a-front-end-entry-form)

Video Tutorial (CraftQuest):
https://craftquest.io/lessons/publishing-entries-from-the-front-end

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the same things that Craft refers to as *elements* and *sections*, you can create a new entry in a section by opening the CMS and navigating to *Entries* using the sidebar menu. Select the desired section, then click the *New entry* button on the upper right. This creates a new unpublished draft, which you can then edit and publish when you're done.

If you mean something else, please explain what you're trying to do in detail.